# Javascript: read http request body as byte array

Tags: javascript, azure-functions

In C# Azure Function, I can convert the string in request body to byte array using

```
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req,  TraceWriter log)
{
    byte[] fileData = await req.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

    ...

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
}
```

How could I do the same thing in JavaScript?

Also how to convert request body into stream in C# and JavaScript?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_api_for_stream_consumers